# Clarification on theorem $(\forall x | R : P) \equiv (\forall x |: R \lor P \equiv P)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Given the theorem $(\forall x | R : P) \equiv (\forall x |: R \lor P \equiv P)$

Since in the second statement we have $R \lor P \equiv P$

Does that mean that I can simply go from the form $(\forall x | R : P)$ to either $(\forall x |: P)$ or $(\forall x | : R)$ else how should this theorem be understood?

Comment: I would recommend not using this $|:$ notation, or at least never with anything between the $|$ and $:$. Instead, always write out what it means $\forall x.(R\Rightarrow P)$. This way the logical structure of the formulas isn't obscured, and you can better separate the quantifiers from the other connectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean that. Think about this in plain language, first. The theorem says, intuitively, that the following statements are equivalent:

- $(i)$ "Every $x$ which satisfies $R$, satisfies $P$."
- $(ii)$ "For every $x$, we have $x$ satisfies $P$ iff $x$ satisfies $R$ or $P$."

Now it should be clear that $(i)$ **doesn't** imply "Every $x$ satisfies $P$" or "Every $x$ satisfies $R$." *(For example, suppose we take $P=R$. Then $(i)$ is trivially true ...)*

For a more concrete example of why this won't work, suppose $R$ is "$x$ is divisible by $4$" and $P$ is "$x$ is even." Then *(in the usual context of the natural numbers)* clearly $(i)$ holds, but also clearly neither "every $x$ satisfies $R$" nor "every $x$ satisfies $P$" holds.

The theorem can be used to do, well, exactly what it says on the tin: from $(i)$ we can deduce $(ii)$, and from $(ii)$ we can deduce $(i)$. Any usage of the theorem which doesn't *exactly* look like this has to be justified, even if it "sort of looks right," and the usages you've proposed cannot in fact be so justified.

---

At this point it might be a good idea to remember why the theorem above is true in the first place.

- $(i)\implies(ii)$: Assuming $(i)$ holds, I want to prove $(ii)$. So let's suppose I have some element $x$. If $x$ satisfies $P$, then clearly $x$ satisfies ($R$ or $P$). Conversely, if $x$ satisfies ($R$ or $P$), there are two choices: $x$ satisfies $P$, in which case we're done, or $x$ satisfies $R$, in which case by $(i)$ we know $x$ also satisfies $P$, and so we're done. So from $(i)$, we've proved $(ii)$.

That is, $(i)$ lets us identify the (seemingly) stronger condition $P$ with the (seemingly) weaker condition $R\vee P$, by telling us that the "alternative to $P$" in the latter in fact still gives us $P$.

- $(ii)\implies (i)$: Assuming $(ii)$ holds, I want to prove $(i)$. So let's suppose I have some $x$ which satisfies $R$. Then clearly $x$ satisfies ($R$ or $P$). But by $(ii)$ this means $x$ satisfies $P$, so we're done.

This time, it's $(ii)$ which is letting us pass from a (seemingly) weaker claim to a (seemingly) stronger claim.

Comment: I usually interpret "$\forall x \mid R : P$ is vacuously true" to mean $\forall x : \lnot R$.  For the case $P=R$ I would say something like "$\forall x \mid R : P$ is trivially true".

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yeah, I like that better. Fixed!

Comment: @MathLearner Not without additional hypotheses; why would you expect to be able to? It should be clear intuitively that the first statement doesn't imply the second. E.g. "For all even $x$, if $x>2$ then $x$ is composite" is true but "For all $x$, if $x>2$ then $x$ is composite" is false. Always think about what the expressions you're looking at mean intuitively, before doing anything technical.